# Como exibir o resultado de uma visão (view) (posgreeSQL) numa página html em PHP?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Olá!! Estou criando uma plataforma web com conexão em postgree e me deparei com esse entrave. Não sei como fazer para exibir uma consulta (view) no formulário HTML recebendo a informação de uma listbox. Alguém poderia me ajudar??

Comment: faz da mesma forma como faria com um select ...  uma view é somente um atalho de uma consulta

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes de como está o seu código e mais detalhes sobre o que você está fazendo? O que você postou é amplo demais, pois existem milhões de formas de fazer isso mas apenas umas poucas servirão para você.